# Softcoding AI in games

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am in the process of developing a game, similar in concept to Risk or Monopoly (a board game, essentially, although what I am asking can be extrapolated). As such, and assuming I would want computer opponents, I would need to write an AI.

Now, my question is whether I need to program the AI directly in the program (hardcoding) or if there exists some way for the program I wrote to read from a list of directions and behavioral rules, *softcoding* the AI.

I assume that if I were to softcode as described before, I would need to program all possible actions that an AI could use. I also assume I can't tell a softmoded AI to do anything, unless programmed (for instance, some decision-making actions that depend on multiple factors). What would be the overhaul (advantages/disadvantages) in softcoding as opposed to hardcoding specific AI?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a [general game playing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_game_playing) engine.

Comment: @tobias_k It isn't quite what I had in mind, although similar. I'm asking if I can program a series of differing AI (say, Smart Computer, Avenging Computer, Expanding Computer, Dumb Computer, etcetera) without integrating them in source code and instead having them in files (such as .txt) and if possible, what would be the overhead involved in making that.

Comment: For different difficulty levels, you could simply make the AI be a bit sloppy, e.g., to what depth to explore a [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) search tree? Concerning the text files, I still think that GGP is relevant, and that you could probably use an existing GGP engine and feed it the rules of your game as a text file or similar. Note that there is a [free online course on GGP](https://www.coursera.org/course/ggp) starting soon over at coursera!

Comment: Thanks for the input (and the coursera link). I'll have to look in more depth into this whole subject. My concrete problem is somewhat localized into my own program and I tried to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some AI techniques are very CPU intensive, such a heuristic based breadth first or depth first search which lends itself to many strategy games.

A search like that would require you establish API such that the current 'state' (a complete representation of the state of the game) could be retrieved, and a list of all possible moves/changes from that state (or any state), and the new state that each of those moves/changes would lead to.

Once you have done this it is possible for any algorithm to make the appropriate API calls to see what states can be moved to, and what states can be moved to from those states, etc. The states that can be reached will grow exponentially the more moves you try to look ahead such that even 2 moves might be a horrendous task for the computer.

Because of this difficulty, heuristic scores are used to evaluate the probably usefulness of following certain branches, thus the search algorithm might discard 90% of the first possible moves from the current state immediately.

An AI that follows this pattern of getting states, evaluating them and looking at possible moves/changes from state to subsequent states, you clearly COULD soft code an AI, but what the AI does in order to heuristically score a state could be anything and your soft code will be like a mini language. Personally, unless for giggles you want to implement a mini language, this is quite a hard work way to do things. Also, your soft code will require some sort of interpretation, which might make it twice as slow as code, or 10 or 100 times slower... and any exponentially difficult techniques will mean that performance is very very important. If the AI method chosen is not exponentially difficult, or plain difficult, soft code could be used, but still you'd have to implement a mini language.

You could of course implement an AI as a separate program that communicates over the network with your game program. This might be just localhost to localhost, but of course it need not be. The performance of this will to some degree depend on network latency and bandwidth, but it may or may not be a significant problem.

You could also implement AIs as dynamically loadable libraries (i.e. your game might look in some folder, see a bunch of lib files and try to load them at run time (e.g. with dlopen() for UNIX). You could then drop new AIs in at any time without touching the game itself. If your main requirements are to have plugin AIs and maintain performance where performance matters, this might be the way to go.

Comment: "As a rule, the type of AI you would implement for this purpose is a heuristic based breadth first or depth first search.". That's absolutely true for a **very limited setting**, and completely wrong for many other types of games. What about chance? What about hidden elements?

Comment: I agree, your comment is useful and well made, though 'very limited' might be over playing it. A chief source of chance in both games posed by the op is dice of course, but in both cases, to varying degree, a search strategy can still be effective. For risk the dice roll is a bias that affects the result probability of an attack on a territory, but this is merely statistical, the army size being a factor too, so a heuristic can calculate a score based on probabilities, in fact the dice roll is largely irrelevant to the decision making process.

Comment: Since the op was not asking about AI technique, but about modular implementation of AIs, integrated or not, my answer probably over emphasises the assertion of a search technique being the way to go anyway. It introduces an important scenario of heavy CPU usage which may or may not be relevant though, and since it may be not only relevant but critical to the choice of implementation that the op is asking about I think it's important. I'll edit the answer a little though to take into account your comments.

Comment: To be fair, the question didn't at all consider CPU performance, mostly because it was a non-issue. For instance, current chess engines calculate the best move in a couple of seconds, and the game I was developing didn't have as many choices as the ones present in a chess game. At the time, I was concerned about the development advantages of having a separate AI file from the program and the possibilities regarding the program's expansion. Due to certain life circumstances the game's development has been frozen since last year.

Comment: I decided to consider CPU in my answer since I considered it potentially crucial to the solution chosen, given the question as it was. You're right a modern chess app, even with a relatively low power CPU, can probably calculate a move in a couple of seconds, though it depends how good it is. Implementing a chess AI is so much more difficult than it seems though, and it's easy to use up the power of modern CPU if one is careless, and that couple of seconds could be quite annoying if it turned into 20 seconds anyway... Good luck if you ever pick up your game development again.